# Why does the order of application search results in the Windows 10 start menu change when adding more letters of their common prefix?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

My question is best demonstrated through an example. I have both `Visual Studio 2015` and `Visual Studio 2017` installed and when I search with the query `vi` in the start menu, it finds them:

[image]

However, to my surprise, when I extend the query to `vis`, the order of the results suddenly changes:

[image]

When adding another letter, the results change even more:

[image]

And when using the full query `visual`, suddenly the results change back:

[image]

This happens despite the fact that both applications have the exact same prefix that matches. What causes this to happen?

This may seem like a petty problem, but this surprise leads to me launching the wrong version of Visual Studio quite often when I click an item by muscle memory, but don't enter the exact same query every time.

Comment: Notice that only once you add the third letter does the full text of `visual Studio 2017` appear in the search box. A clue, perhaps?

Comment: @Twisty Good point, but when extending the query to `visu`, the results change even more.